# SVG security validation using safe-svg jar

Tags: svg

Svg files are validated based on the set of SVG_ELEMENTS,SVG_ATTRIBUTES defined by safe-svg validator jar. So when the svg is implemented by the tags which are not part of SVG_ELEMENTS,SVG_ATTRIBUTES then we are getting violations. So here, in which basis SVG_ELEMENTS,SVG_ATTRIBUTES are defined.
Ex of unsupported tags and attributes by safe-svg jar : missing-glyph,font-face-src,xmlns:xodm,horiz-adv-x

How the SVG_ELEMENTS and SVG_ATTRIBUTES are meant to be valid tag or invalid tags ?
Also do we have any other security validator to validate svg files other than safe-svg jar ?

Comment: those tags were part of SVG 1.1 but were dropped in SVG 2.

Comment: Thanks for the update @RobertLongson.  Do we have any tool to upgrade and modify the svg files to remove the deprecated tags ?

Comment: Lots. Any editor, notepad, vi, emacs, xcode, visual studio.

Comment: Yes I agree. when we use these editors, we need to remove the deprecated items manually. I am requesting for the jar to automatically remove these deprecated tags.

Comment: I suppose you could write an XSLT transform. Asking for tools is off-topic here though.